# Jackson: deserialization of Object Array having different Type Items

Tags: java, arrays, json, object, deserialization

Jackson: Deserialization of Object Array having different Type Items

I am converting an object array to json, that works fine. But when I try to get object array back from json, some items lose their type. For example: `java.sql.Date` object are converted into `String`.

Example:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

list.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
list.add(new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

String text = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(list );

List<Object> deserializeList = objectMapper.readValue(text , TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, valueType));
```

`BigDecimal` is converted to `Integer`

`Date` is converted to `String`

Kindly, help me to maintain the datatype of the object array without using POJO class, i need to return a multi dimension array of object from my server to the client.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't exactly know your needs and your API but the best way to fix your problem is to use a POJO and let Jackson deal with clear data types (not Object).

But ok, you don't want that. What you can do is to implement a custom deserializer for Jackson (see http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers).

If you really want to keep a collection for the serialization / deserialization, just create a new class, child of List, and create a custom deserializer for it.